# MongoDB FindAll() Slow on Enumeration

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have the following block of code, very simple, but it is running extremely slow.

```
Users = new Dictionary<string, MongoUser>();

MongoDatabase ace = GetDatabase();
var users = ace.GetCollection("user").FindAll();

foreach (BsonDocument user in users) // This line takes 14 seconds!
{
   TimeSpan span = DateTime.Now - dt;
   span.ToString();
   MongoUser USER = new MongoUser(user);
   Users.Add(USER.MacAddress, USER);

}
```

This block of code takes about 18 seconds to run. I have profiled each line and determined that the line (marked above) takes almost all the time (14/18 seconds, ~80%). As far as the database goes, the collection I am querying has 740 documents that are extremely simple (i.e. 5 fields, nothing nested). Total size on disk: 0.2MB (so its not network related).

To sum it up:

- Small collection total
- Not using indexes because I'm not querying for a match
- Not network speed
- Slows only on enumeration of MongoCursor

Any ideas? I really thought better of MongoDB and the C# driver than this, I am sure it is something I am doing wrong - thanks!

Comment: How long does it take to return just one user?

Comment: Even If I add a limit on the "find" it takes the same amount of time.

Comment: How about from the MongoDB console? It must be something environmental that's causing the delay.

Comment: From the console on the server it is instantaneous. From a remote computer using the console and mongovue it is instantaneous. Is there a resource that explains what happens when a mongo cursor is enumerated?

Comment: To clarify, this program runs on a computer that is NOT The server. However using the console and mongovue on the same computer that this program runs on results in instantaneous results.

Comment: Hi can you turn profiling on for the collection. On the console type the following: use {yourdbname} then db.setProfilingLevel(2,'{collectionname}'). Re-run your piece of code and execute the following  db.system.profile.find(). This should show you what the driver is executing.